# How to activate the code assistance in IPython Notebook / Jupyter

Tags: scipy, ipython, jupyter

I'm not 100% this is what it is called. I'm taking an online course on pandas. The 'syntax assistance box' keeps popping up for him. Although he is using Notebook and I'm using the latest version of Jupyter.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just press `<Shift>+<Tab>` at the same time when the cursor is right after  the object you information about.

For example:

```
pd.DataFrame
            ^
           cursor
```

or with parenthesis:

```
pd.DataFrame()
             ^
           cursor
```

Now press `<Shift>+<Tab>`.

Works in Firefox and Chrome. Need to test with other browsers.

Comment: Additionally do you know how to get it to appear automatically ?

Comment: I am not aware of such an option. Maybe you can ask another question.